# how to add a comment button to be displayed only for the posts in the home page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, homepage, comment-form

I need a button which directs to the comments section of that particular post. I want that button to be displayed only in the home page for every post.

Can anyone help me with this

My website url is www.thepicz.com and I am using "bulan" theme

Answer (score 1):

In the template part used in the loop on your home page, something like this should get you started. Someplace after `the_content();` or `the_excerpt()`, depending on what you're using.

```
<?php
  if ( is_home() ) { ?>
    <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() );?>#comments">
      Comment Link Text
    </a>
  } 
?>
```

You can make it look like a button with CSS from any of the 80,000 CSS button generators online.

Two things to note:

1. The conditional `is_home()` depends on your blog's set up. You might need `is_front_page()`. Check the codex or ["Tip: is_home() vs is_front_page()"](https://rezzz.com/is_home-vs-is_front_page/). It's possible you wont need it at all if the theme developer already has something like a `content-home.php` set up.
2. The appended `#comments` fragment identifier will need to be changed to match your single.php comment container's ID.